# Select DIstinct with LEFT and COUNT

Tags: mysql

how can i get the query to count the match and return the unique matched values.

**This works good but it returns the unique codes of all plate number of a car**

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(car_number, 2) as letter FROM car_owners ORDER BY letter
```

i want the same but also count how many matches for the same? any hints ??
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the count, instead of using DISTINCT, use GROUP BY to get only one row per distinct first two letters of car_number:

```
select left(car_number, 2) as letter, count(*) from car_owners group by letter
```